# Export from XML file to PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby, xml, postgresql

I have 4Gb xml-file & I need to export it to PostgreSQL.
How to do this with Ruby language? Maybe you can show me some script examples?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Going through your app would be a performance disaster with 4 GB file. (Though only a fraction of those 4 GB will remain once exported as CSV file).

Export the file from Excel to a CSV file and read that into PostgreSQL with [COPY](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-copy.html) - this should also be the fastest way.

For a more detailed answer you would have to put more details into your question.
There is a plethora of realted questions / answers here on SO. Try a search. This one has a [lot of detail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9423888/939860).