# unit testing with in-memory database

Tags: java, unit-testing, postgresql, testing, in-memory-database

I have PostgreSQL database. It is used for unit testing.

- I want to speed the tests up so I want to use some kind of in-memory databases (e.g. H2).
- I want to dump the database (from PostgreSQL) and the import such a dump into in-memory database.

Do you have any suggestion concerning in-memory database choice? I want that database to be compatible with PostgreSQL.

Comment: Have you verified (by measuring) that the bottleneck is your database server's disk IO ? Do you have an idea how much you can improve your test throughput by switching to in-memory database ?

Comment: Which operating system is used for development and testing?

Answer (score 4):

I'd simply create a database directory (called a cluster in PostgreSQL) in tmpfs (essentially a RAM-disk - `/dev/shm` is configured as such in most Linux distributions) and simply run postgres there on non-standard port, for example like this:

```
initdb -D /dev/shm/pgtest
postmaster -D /dev/shm/pgtest -p 11111
```

Comment: this solution is not portable. each member of your team will have to install postgres. CI administrator will have to install postgres. and what if it was a heavyweight database (e.g. oracle)? just no.

Comment: Of course it is not portable. I think installing Postgres isn't too much burden, as most Linux distributions have it packaged. And testing against database other than used in production is not very effective.

Comment: Just a nitpick: You're mixing your terminology. Pg calls a set of databases created by initdb and managed by a postmaster a "cluster" (unfortunate choice of term, but oh well). A [tablespace](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/manage-ag-tablespaces.html) is a subdirectory of the datadir that lets you move some tables, indexes, etc to a different disk.

Comment: @CraigRinger: **PLEASE DON'T!** Never put a tablespace on a ramdisk on any other unstable storage. After reboot, when this tablespace files will be gone or corrupted, **the whole database would not start**.

Comment: @Tometzky Good point, it really needs that caveat. Removed.

Comment: you forgot to mention that `initdb` is not installed by default. `postgres-xc` package is needed on debian. I still can't find it on http://apt.postgresql.org

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using [HSQL](http://hsqldb.org/) with a spring combination. I was brought on to my current occupation to do this exact thing, and even though it is a headache, it can be done. And based on quick research, it appears [hsql is compatible with PostgreSQL](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/management-chapt.html#mtc_compatibility_postgres). Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: Could you tell me why you think it is a headache? Is there Spring necessary? What about H2?

Comment: That `set database sql syntax PGS statement` feature is AWESOME. It's clearly still not as good as testing directly against Pg, but it's very impressive. Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to drop Pg for this?

If you're unit testing against a different database than you run against in production your tests just won't be as good.

Try this: [Optimise PostgreSQL for fast testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9407442/optimise-postgresql-for-fast-testing/9407940#9407940) .

... and see how you go.

*update*: You might think putting everything on a ramdisk will make your tests massively faster, but you're probably mistaken. It's often *more* efficient to let data that isn't in use spill to disk so the system can use more RAM for the task at hand. Using `unlogged` tables and proper async commit or (for testing only, will eat your data) `fsync=off` should get you very similar speeds.

If you *really* require a true in-memory tables, create a file system on a ramdisk or tmpfs and initdb a new cluster in there. You might as well use `UNLOGGED` tables so they don't go through the write-ahead log.

Note that while `tmpfs` is a ramdisk, it allows less-used pages to go to swapspace. If you absolutely must have all the data pinned in RAM for some reason, you'll need to use the `ramdisk` driver and [create a file system on a ramdisk](http://jayant7k.blogspot.com.au/2006/08/ram-disk-in-linux.html) instead. My advice: don't do it. Just configure Pg properly for fast testing.

Comment: I have to make a dump of a PostgreSQL database (schema and some dictionary values). Next, I have to import such dump into in-memory database and then perform all of the unit tests. How can I achieve that?

Comment: @LucasSmith I'm asking *why* the in-memory database is a requirement. Is it purely a performance concern, or is there some other reason? If it's purely performance, a properly configured Pg should run very nearly as fast as an in-memory database when it is working on a data set that fits easily in memory. Trying to go all in-memory may be premature or misdirected optimisation.