# PostgreSQL turn off durabilty

Tags: postgresql, durability

I want to make a script that will run postgres in-memory without durability.
I read this page: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/non-durability.html
But I didn't understand how I can set this parameters in script. Could you please, help me?

Thanks for help!

Comment: What kind of script? Details?

Answer (score 3):

Most of those parameters, like `fsync`, can only be set in `postgresql.conf`. Changes are applied by  re-starting PostgreSQL. They apply to the whole database cluster - all the databases in that PostgreSQL install. That's because the databases all share a single postmaster, [write-ahead log](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/wal-intro.html), and set of shared system tables.

The only parameter listed there that you can set at the SQL level in a script is `synchronous_commit`. By setting `synchronous_commit = 'off'` you can say "it's OK to lose this transaction if the database crashes in the next few seconds, just make sure it still applies atomically".

I wrote more on this topic in a previous answer, [Optimise PostgreSQL for fast testing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9407940/398670).

If you want to set the other params with a script you can do so but you have to do it by opening and modifying `postgresql.conf` using the script, then re-starting PostgreSQL. Text-processing tools like `sed` make this kind of job easier.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running a debian based linux distro, you can just do something like:

```
pg_createcluster -d /dev/shm/mypgcluster 8.4 ramcluster
```

to create a ram based cluster.  Note that you'll have to do:

```
pg_drop cluster 8.4 ramcluster
```

and recreate it on reboot etc.