# Running node-postgres in memory

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

I'm using Node and the [node-postgres package](https://node-postgres.com/) and I would like to perform some unit tests using jest and supertest without saving to the actual database.

When using [sequelize](https://sequelize.org/) it is possible to configure the storage in memory, like so:

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize({
  ...
  storage: ":memory:"
});
```

I know it is possible to set the dialect to Postgres in sequelize, but I was wondering how would one go about to set the in memory storage using node-postgres. Is that possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in sequelize that ":memory:" storage would be available only for sqlite like in memory databases. It isn't possible to run postgresql in memory so you can't connect to in memory postgres from node-postgres/any client.

You can refer this answer for more details ([Using in-memory PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21288667/398670))

Comment: Thank you. Would it be considered a bad practice to create a local database , separated from the actual database, just to run tests?

Comment: That's the way to do it I think. You can have different test database for running tests.

Answer (score 0):

for my approach I'm using docker-container with clear postgres server, which is getting up before all the tests.

then I run all migrations and seeds, then I run all the tests, then I kill that container. All that stuff is done automatically.

But I'm using it in mocha/chai, and using globalSetup and globalTeardown hooks for that. Don't know if it is possible in Jest