# How to create a new postgres database via JDBC and use it directly?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I would like to create a new postgres database via JDBC and use it directly. The problem I have is that the new database is invisible or non standard after creation, so that I cannot create a new connection to it.

My test implementation looks like this:

```java
String url = "jdbc:postgresql://host.docker.internal:54688/";
String username = "postgres";
String password = "...";
try (Connection connObj = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
     Statement stmtObj = connObj.createStatement();) {
    connObj.setAutoCommit(true);

    stmtObj.execute("CREATE DATABASE testdb");
}
catch (SQLException e) {
    fail();
}

String newDbUrl = url + "testdb";
try (Connection newConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(newDbUrl, username, password);
     Statement newStatement = newConnection.createStatement()) {

    newStatement.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE mytable (id serial primary key, name varchar)");
}
catch (SQLException e1) {
    fail(); // <--------- Always fail here
}
```

The code hits always the second SQLException with **org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: database "testdb" does not exist**.

In DBeaver I can see the testdb only if I activate the option "Show all databases".

Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Seems to me like you are trying to create an in-memory postgres db. postgres can't do that. This link provides more information on that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7872693/running-postgresql-in-memory-only

Comment: I tried your code against my PostgreSQL database and it worked just fine, can you share more details about your setup?

If it is a docker environment, you could try to share a minimum reproducible example with the docker files.

Comment: Sure. I always starting a postgres docker with the folowing compose file:

`version: '3.1'

services:

  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: test
    ports:
      - 5432:5432

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8111:8111`

Do you need something else?