# NpgsqlTsVector doesn't work using EF In Memory Database

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, entity-framework, in-memory-database

I have a `NpgsqlTsVector` attribute in my C# class:

```cs
public NpgsqlTsVector Pesquisa { get; set; }
```

I'm using it for searching in the database. It works using the real database.

The problem is in my test class, I'm using `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory` package and getting the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException : The 'NpgsqlTsVector' property 'Produto.Pesquisa' could not be mapped because the database provider does not support this type. Consider converting the property value to a type supported by the database using a value converter. See https://aka.ms/efcore-docs-value-converters for more information.
> Alternately, exclude the property from the model using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

I already tried to ignore this field in `OnModelCreating`, but doing this, the search also doesn't work in the real database.

Comment: There's no expectation for this to work. That's a PostgreSQL-specific feature and won't work with any other database. The in-memory provider isn't even a real database, it's a wrapper over a `Dictionary<>`. Even if you used SQLite in in-memory mode though, you'd get the same error

Comment: Why would you thnk it would work? TsVector is specific to Postgres, the In-Memory DB is another product.

Comment: If you want to unit-test product-specific features you'll have to use a test database.

Comment: Threre's a way to workarround this?

Comment: _"Threre's a way to workarround this?"_ - yes, use real database, for example with testcontainers.

Comment: An almost duplicate question was asked at [Running PostgreSQL in memory only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7872693/running-postgresql-in-memory-only). From the answers you'll see that the easiest option, both for convenience and speed, is to use a test database in a container. There's no in-memory PostgreSQL, emulator projects were abandoned or are still experimental. Testcontainers automate creating and starting up databases for testing and are supported by both VS Code and Visual Studio

Comment: Some of the answers in the almost-duplicate are hacks that can cause problems, like storing the database in a RAM drive tablespace. To avoid harming your installation you'd have to use a container anyway.